# iTunes Search API exclude macSoftware

Tags: json, itunes, url-parameters, itunes-search-api

When using the iTunes Search API I get results for both iOS and Mac software.
I'm looking for a way to exclude the macSoftware results.

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284417353&entity=software,iPadSoftware

**URL: Apple's software on iTunes**

Comment: So you only want `iPadSoftware`?

Comment: No both iPhone and iPad, but no mac software

Comment: Excluding `software` from the query seems to return exactly that. I guess if you need finer adjustments, you will need to filter the JSON yourself.

Comment: excluding software (and just use iPadSoftware) will return mac-software as well.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: Well, it's been two years ago, but I can't remember I did. I found out that the amount of developers that developer for both platforms isn't that great, so I took it for granted. Anyhow, Apple rejected the app.